# Extending from a generic parameter

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Let's suppose I write this class:

```
public A<T> : T
{
}
```

Basically, I want `A` to extend from (inherit) whatever `T` is.

For instance, if I have this:

```
public class B
{
     public string Name { get { return "B"; } }
}
```

I should be able to accomplish something like this:

```
B instance = new A<B>();
Console.WriteLine(instance.Name);
```

which doesn't compile.

How can I extend from a generic argument?

If it can't be done, why is it not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because even though you could write a constraint to say "it has to be a class"...

```
// NOT WORKING CODE...
public class B<T> : T where T : class
```

... there is no guarantee the class isn't sealed.

This is why the compiler says you can't do it.

What you can do is create a real base class and constrain T to that base class and inherit from the base class...

```
public class B<T> : BaseType where T : BaseType
```

Example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
}

public class A : BaseClass
{
}

public class B<T> : BaseClass where T : class
{
}
```

Usage:

```
var x = new B<A>();
```

Comment: Not to mention that it would make tons of things extremely tricky - for example, overload resolution. You can't inherit from something that isn't defined in .NET. There's a bit on the MSDN page as well - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184590(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you could make it work:

```
class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        B instance = new A<B>();
        Console.WriteLine(instance.Name);
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class A<T> : B where T : B { }

public class B
{
    public string Name { get { return "B"; } }
}
```

Although, `A` should really just inherit from `B` directly here.  Not sure what your end goal is.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps rather than trying to create a class that inherits generics you could create an extension method to perform the task you're looking for.

```
public static void ExtensionTest<T>(this T test)
{
  Console.WriteLine("ExtensionTest");
}
```

In use:

```
var b = new B();
b.ExtensionTest();
```